# JUnit test starts Jetty, Jetty starts Spring, can test see spring application context

Tags: java, spring, jetty

This is for some high level Web/Rest tests of my whole system that are being powered by Jetty/Spring.

What I am trying to do is to have a completely self contained test that,

- Starts Jetty which starts the Application
- Application starts Spring
- Test uses Webdriver / RestAssured to hit application and test behavior
- Test checks DB for changed data

What I am trying to do is have the whole thing running in a single JVM, i.e. I'm starting a org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.
This is because its easy, and avoids the test having outside dependencies (like starting Jetty)

This is all cool, but I hate that I have to check the DB manually ... I want to use my DAO (or maybe service layer) classes so I'm not re-writing DB code.

Since my DAO's have already been started by Spring in the Jetty instance in the **same JVM** as the test case, I want to grab that ApplicationContext and then pull my DAO beans out.

I'm a bit stuck getting the ApplicationContext since the test isn't a "Spring" test per say.

People got any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you build another context in your tests and use different instances of dao classes? Scenario you are describing sounds like maven integration tests (failsafe plugin) with jetty plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm specifically avoiding the Maven plugins as an experiment to make the tests self contained ... at the moment you can run the junit test just like any other test and not need maven or any other build tool to manage things ... this comes from pain experienced on many projects with Mavens integration test model. I'll probably be moving this to Gradle so I can have more separation between different types of tests than what maven provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible to access the spring context in jetty if it is start normally, may it could work if you use some embedded server.

But I think there are much simpler solutions:

- use a second (different) spring context for the tests, this can be smaller than the "normal" one, because you will not need all the services and controllers, or
- add some json or webservice query interface in your Server, that simply returns the requested result from the database. Then you can access the database from your tests via that interface in the server. -- I think you only need two or three different querys per entity, so it should be not so much work, (but I would prefer the other solution).

Comment: Thanks @Ralph, I've used both methods before in different projects when the app server instance was in a separate JVM from the test. But because I'm starting Jetty in the same JVM, I was keen to know if there was a hook in Spring I could use.

The first option works ok, but only for hooking into a shared resource like the DB. Say I need to hook into the service layer for something that is in-memory then the first option falls down.

The second option is more effort which I'm trying to avoid by running everything in one JVM.

Comment: You can also have a lock at Arquillian http://www.jboss.org/arquillian - I dont know if it is helpfull for this scenarion, but it can somehow connect a test with an EJB/CDI container, mabye it works with spring too.

Comment: Haven't used Arquillian as i'm not doing EJB/CDI stuff, and I'm never going to use JBoss. Locking this in as it is the best answer so far ... for the time being I'm going with the first solution, which works ok and allows me to reuse my tests if I want to use a remote jetty instance (which I can control with system props). I would still like to figure out if I can hook into the same app context, just as a thought exercise for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

@Ralph's answer is the best - use a separate spring context for the tests. Ideally, you should refactor out all the DAO beans and their dependencies into a separate `dao-beans.xml` that you can include in your main app context and your test context..

Alternatively, you can use Spring Remoting to export the DAO beans from the Jetty server via RMI or HTTP by adding a ServiceExporter bean to your (real) app context

```
<bean name="daoExporter"
        class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
    <property name="service">
        <ref bean="dao" />
    </property>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.example.IDao" />
</bean>
```

and a custom Spring remoting servlet in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>daoServiceExporter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>daoServiceExporter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/remoting/dao</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then importing it into your test context

```
<bean id="dao" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.example.IDao" />
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="http://localhost:8080/remoting/dao"/>
</bean>
```

This is only a better answer if e.g. it takes a long time for your Spring context to load, or maybe you have some beans that must remain singletons.

Comment: +1 for idea to use Spring Remoting, this is better than my "handwritten" json idea.

Comment: Nice solution, Similar to the comment above DAO's are generally easy to start in a separate spring application context, since they just share a DB.  
But this would be a nice way to export services that may involved more than the DB.